# jQuery: For loop if else and nth-child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
 for (i = 1; i < 24; i++){{ 

       if(dices[i].value == 0) {
            $('td div:nth-child(i)').addClass("zero-desktop")
          } else if (dices[i].value == 1) {  
            $('td div:nth-child(i)').addClass("one-desktop") 
          } else if (dices[i].value == 2){
            $('td div:nth-child(i)').addClass("two-desktop")
          } else if (dices[i].value == 3) {
            $('td div:nth-child(i)').addClass("three-desktop") 
          } else if (dices[i].value == 4) {
            $('td div:nth-child(i)').addClass("four-desktop")
          } else {
              alert ("NOT WORKING")
          }
          }};
```

`dices[i]` is an array that displays 23 random numbers and there are 23 divs.

Each time `dice[i].value` equals to one of (0~4), class will be added to div and when it successfully adds a class to div, `[i]` will increment until it reaches the end number.

For some reason uncaught *Error:syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child error* shows up.

Comment: Would you be able to paste the dices array too please?

Comment: dices is an array that generates 23 random number. for example dice[2] can range from 0~4 and changes every time i refresh the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are literally inserting the character `'i'` in your selectors instead of using the variable `i`. You should use string concatenation, like this:

```
for (i = 1; i < 24; i++) { 
  if (dices[i].value == 0) {
    $('td div:nth-child(' + i + ')').addClass("zero-desktop")
  } else if (dices[i].value == 1) {  
    $('td div:nth-child(' + i + ')').addClass("one-desktop") 
  } else if (dices[i].value == 2){
    $('td div:nth-child(' + i + ')').addClass("two-desktop")
  } else if (dices[i].value == 3) {
    $('td div:nth-child(' + i + ')').addClass("three-desktop") 
  } else if (dices[i].value == 4) {
    $('td div:nth-child(' + i + ')').addClass("four-desktop")
  } else {
    alert ("NOT WORKING")
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck with the rest of your project :)

Comment: Hey, I noticed you decided to unaccept my answer. Is this for any particular reason? I may be able to help you with whatever new problem has arisen. Let me know :)

Comment: Sorry about that i didn't know i unchecked it :)